# Excel Pivot table range update via VBA gets too many rows

Tags: excel, vba, automation, pivot-table

I'm using Excel 2016 and I'm pulling data from a SharePoint list. Once the data is pulled in, I have 3 rows inserted at the beginning of the data list and some data inserted. I then launch a Sub to update the pivot tables to pickup the new data and extend the old range of the table so it picks up all of the data. It picks up all of the data, but the range extends beyond the table itself. It ends up picking up two extra rows that aren't a part of the data list. Seen in the picture  below, it should only pick up to row 11, but it picks up to row 13. This adds two rows of blank data throwing off the look of the pivot tables. The code that pulls the range information is shown between the asterisks.

[Data List Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ0jU.png)

```
Sub UpdateTable()
 Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
 Dim Pivot_Sheet As Worksheet
 Dim StartPoint As Range
 Dim DataRange As Range
 Dim PivotName As String
 Dim PivotTables(3) As String
 Dim Table As Integer
 Dim NewRange As String
 Dim LastCol As Long
 Dim lastRow As Long

 'MsgBox Prompt:="Running UpdateTable"

 
 'Set Pivot Table & Source Worksheet
 Set Data_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("owssvr")
 Set Pivot_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
 
 PivotTables(0) = "pvtOverOpen"
 PivotTables(1) = "pvtOverAgeBracket"
 PivotTables(2) = "pvtOverCreate"
 PivotTables(3) = "pvtOverClosed"
 'Loop through each pivot table and update it
 For Table = 0 To 3 Step 1
 'Enter in Pivot Table Name
 PivotName = PivotTables(Table)
 'Defining Staring Point & Dynamic Range
 Data_Sheet.Activate
'**********************************************************************************
 Set StartPoint = Data_Sheet.Range("A1")
 Set DataRange = Data_Sheet.Range(StartPoint, StartPoint.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
 NewRange = Data_Sheet.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
 'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address
 Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName). _
 ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
 PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)
'***********************************************************************************
 MsgBox Prompt:=NewRange
 'Ensure Pivot Table is Refreshed
 Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable
 'End of For Loop
 Next Table
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using the name of the table for the reference, as it will expand with the table and avoid the pivot grabbing rows outside of that named range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a fix. It was an old method I was using that decided to work. This is the code snippet that I used that grabbed the exact range of the data:

```
Set StartPoint = Data_Sheet.Range("A1")
 LastCol = StartPoint.End(xlToRight).Column
 DownCell = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row
 Set DataRange = Data_Sheet.Range(StartPoint, Cells(DownCell, LastCol))
 NewRange = Data_Sheet.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your used range? Take a look at the link below to find out more about your actual used range.

https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2012/03/01/select-actual-used-range-in-excel-sheet/

Delete any rows/column that are not in your intended used range, save your workbook, and then create your pivot table.